# Trying to re-size a div with an event listener

Tags: javascript

Trying to make a div resize from 100px by 100px to 200px by 200px by using the event listener mouse over. I can't quite figure out the syntax to change it. Heres my current function. After width I don't know what to add to double the size.

```
function handleMouseover(event) {
event.target.style.width

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function handleMouseover(event) {
event.target.style.width = "200px";
event.target.style.height = "200px";


}
```

Comment: To double the size you could do `event.target.style.width = 2*event.target.style.width;`